# How to get the Text from a DataGrid cell c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, cell

[image: What I have to reproduce]

Hi, I have to create this on Visual Studio with c# on application WPF. The data came from a file. I know how to extract the data and put it in the DataGrid, but I absolutely don't know how to get the value of the cell... For example I want to get the "1.3" when the user changed the value of the cell.

[image: What I have done]

Comment: You should get the value of the object of type T in the IEnumerable<T> ItemsSource of the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CellEditEnding Event of datagrid. When the user changes the value in a cell, the event will be fired

Comment: Thanks it confirmed my thought ! I have already tried this but I am a beginner so i don't know how to proceed inside the method to get the values of the line or the cell.